# How to specify version label in CircleCI deployments to AWS ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, circleci

I am using Circle CI to deploy my java application to elasticbeanstalk.

But I am not able to specify a version for my release. the release label looks like `app-1234-staging-1234-1234` is there any way that I can specify an application version, like `myapp.4.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer, It was an easy one. You can pass the label along with the deploy command

```
eb deploy -l "RELEASE-VERSION-4.0.1"
```